# setChecked is not working

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a listview with toggle buttons. All thing is going well, the issue is with toggle button's method `setChecked`. The button is automatically set to off set by itself, on going down to the list view. I am using a custom adapter and here is the `getView` method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Holder holder = new Holder();

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout,null);

        holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item);
        holder.tb = (ToggleButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tgl_status);

        holder.tv.setText(Name.get(position));


        holder.tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    // The toggle is enabled
                    holder.tb.setChecked(isChecked);
                    Toast.makeText(activity, Name.get(position) + "ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // The toggle is disabled
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    holder.tb.setChecked(isChecked);
                }
            }
        });

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(activity, "You Clicked "+Name.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
```

Issue is with :

> holder.tb.setChecked(isChecked);

It is always false.

My `list_view_layout.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tgl_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am using a fragment which uses this custom adapter.

Comment: I assume that if you will set it to checked in your `list_view_layout.xml` the value would be always true?

Comment: Yeah, but I have not done anything like this in 'list_view_layout.xml'

Comment: Your both `holder.tb.setChecked(isChecked);` lines are without sense. This Toggle already has this state (as it is taken from changestatelistener, and there is not sense to set it again for the same value, as have already.

Comment: But, if toggle button is on, it goes off when I go away from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a problem here.

You're checking/unchecking this `ToggleButton` **IN** the `CheckedChangeListener`. That is: when you check this `ToggleButton`, your `onCheckedChange` will check it again. You're duplicating a not needed action.

If you're actually trying to check it according to a object (Let's say `Weather`) in your `ArrayList` of `Weathers` inside your `Adapter`, then you should go for:

```
if (weatherList.get(position).isChecked) { 
    holder.tb.setChecked(true);
} else { 
    holder.tb.setChecked(false);
}
```

Comment: answer is confusing :D . A lots of checkeds. It's not working other way

Comment: It's not confusing. A `Listener` does what it's name already explains: it listen to **something**. In this case, you're listening for the actions of CHECKING / UNCHECKING your ToggleButton.

Comment: Then how can I save the current state of the toggle button?

Comment: Edited. See if it helps you.

Comment: My issue is that if I toggle button is off, I on it, now I scroll down and scroll up, then toggle button goes off.

Comment: You must somehow save the state of your `ToggleButton`. Quick review:  An `Adapter` is supposed to show values of a collection of objects in a `ListView`, `GridView` or whatever. Every entry of this collection of objects must have a variable which will be used to store the state of your `ToggleButton`. Your `ToggleButton` is losing it's state because 1) you're not even saving it in an variable and 2) you're not setting it in your `getView` method of your `Adapter`. Simple enough.

Comment: Yeah, Now I got the point. The point 1 is clear. I need a variable for it. Now for 2nd point, how can I set in my getView method?

Comment: Inside your Adapter you probably have a collection of objects that you wish to display. Notice how the getView method gives you a "position" parameter: thats the key. Use this integer to get a object from your collection. This object must have a boolean attribute which you'll use to set your ToggleButton checked or not.